# How to 'Expo' One Big Wall with Dual Monitors

Tags: 11.04, compiz, nvidia, multiple-monitors

With Dual Monitors, when I use the Expo, it clones repeating itself in each monitor. With 10.10 I solved this with the option 'One Big Wall' but this doesn't work on 11.04

I have a [nvidia 560Ti](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-560ti-us.html) with proprietary drivers.

Comment: did you try twin view?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score -1):

Let's have some fun here.... I just read on some sites, and I just got some fix. I didn't try it yet because have no testing box.

You need to install a package from the new PPA (which are you going to insert it into your ubuntu).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:disper-dev/ppa

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nmellegard/disper-indicator-ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install disper disper-indicator
```

After the installation completed successfully, run this command from the terminal

```
disper -e
```

It will detect the resolution automatically and extend the desktop, without cloning them. I hope this guide will help you. But if this way is not working, you might try the second one....

The second directly use the system that already pre-installed in the machine called xrandr. You might want to use the graphical one, called grandr

```
sudo apt-get install grandr
```

For me, grandr is very useful to set the custom resolution for the each of the monitor. And then, to activate the extended view, you can use this command line. Insert it into your terminal and it will work like a charm....

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --right-of LVDS1
```

Assume that your are using the LVDS display (from the laptop) and the VGA display from the connected Monitor. How to know my monitor? Easy, by using the `xrandr -q` directly from your terminal. This my output :

[image: My output]

If the terminal shows VGA1 and VGA2, just replace my command line above. And of course, feel free to examine with the command line given. Maybe it is fun (I guess)

Psst : I've already tried this with Ubuntu with the LXDE and XFCE environment for the second opinion. For the first one, I didn't try yet because I have no nVidia-powered box to test on. Enjoy.

Erm.... for the KDE users, don't worry because you can set the extended diplay directly from the System Setting.

[image: My output]